# Does idiomatic language improve my speaking score in IELTS?

Tags: idiomatic-language, ielts

If I use a very idiomatic language in speaking test, I gain point or lose point?
For example suppose instead of saying:

> Medical graduates are considered the best in our university.

I say:

> Medical graduates are considered as cream of the crop in our university.

Which one is better in IELTS speaking exam?

Comment: I have no idea, but I expect it's more important to use idiomatic grammar.  Neither of your sentences is 100% correct.  Moreover I'm confused by "medical graduates".  Do you mean "medical students"?  "Graduates" are no longer *in* the university, you see.  Plus various other errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English but about how a certain test is graded. Not even sure why there's an `ielts` tag in the first place.

Comment: cream of the crop is a perfectly respectable cliché.

Answer (score 1):

Students who earn a medical degree are considered to be the cream of crop of all the graduates at our university.

It is a good idea to write and speak idiomatically. They are many ways to express the sentence above, I provided one possibility.

cream of the crop is a cliché and an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sure. For this reason, we suggest that you employ as many idioms and collocations as you can. Your English will sound much more natural and fluid as a result. As often as you can, practice speaking, ideally with native speakers. The ability to use idioms in conversation will set native English speakers apart from intermediate English language learners.

For that too, you can further expand the number of [vocabulary IELTS Test](https://www.ieltsclue.com/p/ielts-vocabulary.html), so that it will help in answering [IELTS questions](https://www.ieltsclue.com/p/ielts-vocabulary.html)

Even though the words in a collocation are not together, the meaning can still be understood. If the words are split, idioms lose their meaning.

Comment: Can you edit this to explain what you mean by using collocations?